# Sending Data Between Two Forms C#

Tags: c#, winforms

[Click to see problem explain by Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qahpG.jpg) i have two form ...
on form1 there is a submit button which when pressed form2 should be open with username textbox and submit button ....
when user press submit button form1 will be appeared again and button text will be change to username and new sign up button will appear ....

it works for first press but on second button press first button text goes to default text , how to fix this ?

class 1

```
namespace Internship_Test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


        }    

        public string b;

        public Form1(Form2 obj)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            if(button1.Name == obj.b2)
            {
                button1.Text = obj.username;
                button2.Visible = true;

            }
            else if(button2.Name == obj.b2)
            {

                button2.Visible = true;
                button2.Text = obj.username;
                button3.Visible = true;
            }
            else if (button3.Name == obj.b2)
            {
                button2.Visible = true;
                button3.Visible = true;
                button3.Text = obj.username;
                button4.Visible = true;
            }
            else if (button4.Name == obj.b2)
            {
                button2.Visible = true;
                button3.Visible = true;
                button4.Visible = true;
                button4.Text = obj.username;
                button5.Visible = true;
            }
            else if (button4.Name == obj.b2)
            {
                button2.Visible = true;
                button3.Visible = true;
                button4.Visible = true;
                button5.Visible = true;
                button5.Text = obj.username;
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.b = ((Button)sender).Name;
            Form2 obj = new Form2(this);
            obj.ShowDialog();
            this.Hide();

        }
    }
}
```

class 2

```
namespace Internship_Test
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        string[] user = new string[5];
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }
        public string b2;
        public Form2(Form1 obj)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            b2 = obj.b;

        }

        public string username;

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            username = textBox2.Text;
            Form1 obj = new Form1(this);
            obj.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
    }
}[Click to see problem explain by Image ][1]
```

Comment: Don't "send" anything between the forms. Remove business logic from the forms and place it in separate objects (MVC is a nice architecture). Then have the forms bind to and respond to events from the business objects.

Comment: it seems that your `if` statements are never `true` in the constructor of `Form1`. This might be because you create in `button1_Click` a new `Form1` instance which has default names for the buttons. How are the if statements evaluated when you step through it in the debugger?

Comment: Have u check the image ?

Comment: i don't know where i am wrong ... 
plz see the image & tell me how to resolve this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As response on your question/bug, like Mong Zhu pointed out:

Your bug is found here:

```
class 2

namespace Internship_Test
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        string[] user = new string[5];
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }
        public string b2;

        private Form1 _form1;   // you need to create a field for the form1

        public Form2(Form1 form1)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            b2 = obj.b;
            _form1 = form1; 

        }

        public string username;

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            username = textBox2.Text;
            //Form1 obj = new Form1(this);
            // instead of creating a new form, just pop it up:
            _form1?.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
    }
}
```

And you should change the `obj.ShowDialog();` to `obj.Show();`

Answer (score 0):

Some questions:

- Why would you hide the form1?
- Why are you pass an instance of Form2 into the constructor of Form1?

I would implement it like:

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using(var form2 = new Form2())
        {
            // if you want to fill the username before popup..
            // do it here:
            // form2.UserName = textBox2.Text;

            var result = form2.ShowDialog();

            if(result != DialogResult.OK)
                return;

            textBox2.Text = form2.UserName;
        }
    }
}

public class Form2 : Form
{
    public string UserName
    {
        get { return textBox1.Text; }
        set { textBox1.Text = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: check the image at the start of question

Comment: It updates correctly on first sign up click but on second first button text change to its default value

Comment: The UI is kinda confusing. Why do you want to click multiple times on signup?

Comment: Firstly their will b one button wd text sign up ...
When we click it Form2 wd username textbox and submit button will appear ..
we will write a username and click submit .... 

when submit button is pressed , we will go back to Form1 and this time button text has to be changed to username we type in Form2 and new button with Sign Up text will appear under it.

Comment: Now when we click new Submit Button the same procedure has to be repeat for 5 new sign up buttons

Comment: It works for me when their is only one sign up button we go to Form2 and set username in button text ....
but when i go for second button , first button text changes to Sign Up as its default value ....

The issue is how to save first button value ?

Comment: How many signup buttons do you want to appear? (maximum?) What happens if you press a button with a name?

Comment: 5 sign up button
nothing should happen if we press a button with username ...

The thing happens only when we press button with sign up text -> Form2 will open , we write a username and when we click submit button on form2 ... -> go back to form1 the button text changes to username we write in second form and new button with sign up text should appear ...
and this process repeats with 5 new buttons which comes one by one ...